# Как преобразовать строку на кириллице в кодировке utf8 в нижний регистр на C++ средствами std?

Tags: c++

Этот код не работает с кириллицей в кодировке utf8

```
std::string s{"Тест"};
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char c) -> char {
    return std::tolower(c, std::locale());
});
std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Для начала следует разобраться, в какой кодировке представлена исходная строка. Кодировки "кириллица" нет. Затем поставить библиотеку ICU и воспользоваться ей.

Comment: @user7860670, желательно сделать так, чтобы было независимо от кодировки

Comment: Эта операция однозначно зависит от кодировки.

Comment: @user7860670, кодировка utf8, значит средствами std нельзя?

Comment: Нельзя. tolower например принимает на вход один char (который надо кстати кастовать в unsigned char), а в utf-8 кириллические символы занимают больше одного `char`. Тут даже на этапе итерации по символам не работает.

Comment: @user7860670, почему тогда std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) -> char { std::cout << c; }); работает?

Comment: оно не работает...

Comment: @user7860670, https://onlinegdb.com/vdkCmNILH

Comment: Это называется случайное стечение обстоятельств. При такой итерации кириллические символы utf-8 разрываются на два и т.д.

Comment: @user7860670, там 8 итераций, видимо поток вывода понимает такую последовательность.

Comment: Сам алгоритм прост. Достаточно посмотреть на любую таблицу [кириллицы в utf-8](http://blog.kislenko.net/show.php?id=2045). Легко заметить, что у всех букв  `А`-`П` первый байт 0xD0, а второй от 0x90 до 0x9F. Для перевода их в lowcase (`а`-`п`) достаточно прибавить 32 ко второму байту.  У  букв `Р`-`Я` первый байт также 0xD0, а второй от 0xA0 до 0xAF. Для их перевода надо добавить 1 к первому байту, а во втором сбросить биты 4 и 5 (т.е. выполнить `chars[i + 1] &= ~0x30`, если `i` это текущий индекс первого байта рассматриваемого символа в utf-8).

Comment: Отдельно надо проверить `Ё` (коды 2-х байт 0xD081). Ее байты проще всего просто заменить на 0xD191 / Ну, а вожделенный STL, сами как-нибудь присобачьте

Answer (score 2):

По своим же комментариям набросал код

```
  char *s = 0;
  size_t n = 0;

  while (getline(&s, &n, stdin) >= 0) {
    for (unsigned char *p = s; *p; p++) {
      if (p[0] == 0xD0) {
        if (0x90 <= p[1] && p[1] <= 0x9F)
          p[1] += 32;
        else if (0xA0 <= p[1] && p[1] <= 0xAF)
          p[0] += 1, p[1] &= ~0x30;
        else if (p[1] == 0x81)
          p[0] = 0xD1, p[1] = 0x91;
      }
    }

    puts(s);
  }
```

Жаль, длинноват для комментария, но может кому-нибудь пригодится.

Тогда уж, перенесу сюда и комментарий, поясняющий его.

---

Сам алгоритм прост. Достаточно посмотреть на любую [таблицу кириллицы в utf-8](http://blog.kislenko.net/show.php?id=2045).

Легко заметить, что у всех букв `А`-`П` первый байт **0xD0**, а второй от **0x90** до **0x9F**. Для перевода их в lowcase (`а`-`п`) достаточно **прибавить 32** ко второму байту.

У букв `Р`-`Я` первый байт также **0xD0**, а второй от **0xA0** до **0xAF**. Для их перевода надо **добавить 1** к первому байту, а во втором **сбросить биты 4 и 5** (т.е. выполнить `chars[i + 1] &= ~0x30`, если `i` это текущий индекс первого байта рассматриваемого символа в utf-8).

Отдельно надо проверить `Ё` (коды 2-х байт **0xD081**). Ее байты проще всего просто заменить на **0xD191**.

Comment: В описании следует отметить, что алгоритм корректен даже если буквы "Й" и "Ё" представлены в форме декомпозиции, т.е. как "И\u0306" и "Е\u0308" (форма NFD часто встречается в macOS и iOS), и будет получен результат "и\u0306" и "е\u0308".

Comment: Да, хотя если определён `__STDC_ISO_10646__`, эту задачу и можно реализовать средствами стандартной библиотеки, т.e. преобразовать в `std::wstring` для locale с UTF-8 и обратно, но этот код шустрее.

Comment: @Serge3leo, следует отметить, что этот код работает прямо с utf-8 (тем что обычно лежит в файлах в Linux) и читается без всяких преобразований к `wchar_t`

Answer (score -1):

Единственный способ который точно будет работать и на Windows и на Linux, это использовать `wchar_t` вместо `char`. А так как мы живем во времена когда у С++ появилась `filesystem` и `std::filesystem::path` то преобразовывать строки из `char` в `wchar_t` можно через `path`.

А вот собственно и функция:

```
 #include <string>
 #include <filesytem> 
     
 void ToLower(std::string string) {
        std::wstring ws = std::filesystem::path(string).native();
        std::wstring outWs;
        std::string outS;

        for (wchar_t wc : ws) {

            unsigned int c = (unsigned int)wc;
            switch (c) {
                case L'A': outWs += 'a'; break;
                case L'B': outWs += 'b'; break;
                case L'C': outWs += 'c'; break;
                case L'D': outWs += 'd'; break;
                case L'E': outWs += 'e'; break;
                case L'F': outWs += 'f'; break;
                case L'G': outWs += 'g'; break;
                case L'H': outWs += 'h'; break;
                case L'I': outWs += 'i'; break;
                case L'J': outWs += 'j'; break;
                case L'K': outWs += 'k'; break;
                case L'L': outWs += 'l'; break;
                case L'M': outWs += 'm'; break;
                case L'N': outWs += 'n'; break;
                case L'O': outWs += 'o'; break;
                case L'P': outWs += 'p'; break;
                case L'Q': outWs += 'q'; break;
                case L'R': outWs += 'r'; break;
                case L'S': outWs += 's'; break;
                case L'T': outWs += 't'; break;
                case L'U': outWs += 'u'; break;
                case L'V': outWs += 'v'; break;
                case L'W': outWs += 'w'; break;
                case L'X': outWs += 'x'; break;
                case L'Y': outWs += 'y'; break;
                case L'Z': outWs += 'z'; break;

                case L'А': outWs += L'а'; break;
                case L'Б': outWs += L'б'; break;
                case L'В': outWs += L'в'; break;
                case L'Г': outWs += L'г'; break;
                case L'Д': outWs += L'д'; break;
                case L'Е': outWs += L'е'; break;
                case L'Ж': outWs += L'ж'; break;
                case L'З': outWs += L'з'; break;
                case L'И': outWs += L'и'; break;
                case L'Й': outWs += L'й'; break;
                case L'К': outWs += L'к'; break;
                case L'Л': outWs += L'л'; break;
                case L'Н': outWs += L'н'; break;
                case L'М': outWs += L'м'; break;
                case L'О': outWs += L'о'; break;
                case L'П': outWs += L'п'; break;
                case L'Р': outWs += L'р'; break;
                case L'С': outWs += L'с'; break;
                case L'Т': outWs += L'т'; break;
                case L'У': outWs += L'у'; break;
                case L'Ф': outWs += L'ф'; break;
                case L'Х': outWs += L'х'; break;
                case L'Ц': outWs += L'ц'; break;
                case L'Ч': outWs += L'ч'; break;
                case L'Ш': outWs += L'ш'; break;
                case L'Щ': outWs += L'щ'; break;
                case L'Ь': outWs += L'ь'; break;
                case L'Ъ': outWs += L'ъ'; break;
                case L'Ы': outWs += L'ы'; break;
                case L'Э': outWs += L'э'; break;
                case L'Ю': outWs += L'ю'; break;
                case L'Я': outWs += L'я'; break;
                default: {
                    outWs += wc; break;
                }
            }
        }

        string = std::filesystem::path(outWs).string();
    }


    int main() {
        std::string s = "Съешь Ещё Этих Мягких Французских Булок Да Выпей Чаю";
        ToLower(s);
        std::cout << s << std::end;
      
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Вы это тестировали на MSVC? Когда я последний раз проверял, оно не работало без юникодной локали (либо нужно было использовать функции с `...u8...` в названии).

Comment: И вообще, если уж список букв все равно захардкожен, я бы оперировал сразу на UTF-8.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я этот код писал и тестировал на MSVC, из все решений для меня это было самое подходящие.  А насчет локали, это не цель этого кода, тут просто все символы в строке заменяются на маленькие. А если надо вывести его в консоль то конечно нужно будет установить локаль.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat К примеру я пишу игровой движок в котором я вывожу текст в свою консоль и для этого мне не нужно использовать ни какой локаль.

Comment: Я не про консоль говорю, а про то, что вызовы каких-то методов на юникодных путях кидаются исключениями если не поставить локаль.

Comment: Судя по https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/909?ysclid=lhzcm4rb70567894052, по умолчанию `path` ожидает не UTF-8, а текущую однобайтную кодировку (в случае русской локали - WINDOWS-1251?). Вы уверены, что у вас сорцы сохранены в utf8, а не в win1251?